# The publication 'My_publication' doesn't exist?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactional-replication

We are trying to test the success of Transactional replications.
by Googling , i found that i need to execute in our publisher this stored procedure :

[sp_publication_validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-publication-validation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

However , When i execute :

```
exec sys.sp_publication_validation 
@publication=ReplicationFaouzi,
@rowcount_only=0,
@full_or_fast=0,
@shutdown_agent=0
```

I get this error :

> Msg 20026, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSpublication_validation, Line 57
>       The publication 'ReplicationFaouzi' doesn't exist ?

When i run this sql :

```
SELECT publication
FROM MSpublications
ORDER BY publication
```

I get in Result :

```
ReplicationFaouzi
```

what is wrong ?

## Update

By checking the code of this stored procedure i found that it calls un-found stored procedure  ***sys.sp_MSreplcheck_publish*** and ***sys.sp_MSrepl_getpublisherinfo*** :

```
exec @retcode = sys.sp_MSreplcheck_publish
if @@error <> 0 or @retcode <> 0
begin
    return (1)
end

EXEC @retcode = sys.sp_MSrepl_getpublisherinfo  @publisher      = @publisher,
                                                @publisher_type = @publisher_type OUTPUT,
                                                @rpcheader      = @cmd OUTPUT
```

**sys.sp_MSreplcheck_publish** exist under a database named model ,and i can't find **sys.sp_MSrepl_getpublisherinfo**!!

## Update 2

My Team re-created the  replication database and  now  this sql command:

```
 SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE is_published = 1;
```

dosen't return any value , but this :

```
 SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE is_merge_published = 1;
```

returns 'Guichet'

Now, when  i run :

```
USE [Guichet];
GO
EXEC sp_helppublication;
```

I get nothing  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run that procedure in the context of the publication database (the database that is the source of the data you wish to replicate).  You can do that with a `USE` statement:

```
USE [YourDatabaseName];
GO

EXEC sys.sp_publication_validation 
    @publication=ReplicationFaouzi,
    @rowcount_only=0,
    @full_or_fast=0,
    @shutdown_agent=0
```

If you're unsure of which database is the publication database, you can run this query to find which databases are configured as publishers:

```
SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases WHERE is_published = 1;
```

Once you have the database name from that query, you can run this to see the name of the actual publications that should be passed to `sp_publication_validation`.  In your case, the publisher is named `Guichet`, so you'd run:

```
USE [Guichet];
GO
EXEC sp_helppublication;
```

This will give you the value that needs to be passed to the `@publication` parameter.

---

Note that all of the above is written in the context of *transaction* replication (which is what the original question was about).  Different steps are required for different types of replication.

There is a great "information gathering" script on the Microsoft Docs website that walks through getting info on distributors and publishers when using different types of replication:

[Distributor and Publisher Information Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/distributor-and-publisher-information-script?view=sql-server-2017)